# How to change linked SVG image to included SVG image in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, import, href, inkscape, xlink

When importing external SVG images the Inkscape offers three options:

- Include SVG image as editable object(s) in the current file
- Embed the SVG file in a image tag (not editable in this document)
- Link the SVG file in a image tag (not editable in this document)

At first, for convenience I imported an SVG images (Image A) into master SVG image B in the third way (Link the SVG file) so that when editing image A, master image B changes accordingly. However, later in the publishing process, I found that I needed to make sure every part in master image B had to be editable, including those parts within image A.

Had I imported image A in the first way above (include SVG image), this would be possible. I had made some transformations to the linked image A within master image B so I didn't want to do it again. Is there a way to transform a linked image (`<image xlink:href="XXX.svg" />`) to an included image (`<svg>...</svg>`) with just a few clicks while preserving all the transformations I did to this image?

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the image and select 'Embed image'. This is going to embed it as an image, `<svg:image ...>`, though, not as an svg (I think that would be invalid SVG code, too).

For multiple images, use the extension 'Extensions > Images > Embed Images' without any image selected (or with all of them).

Comment: I know these options but they are just what I want to avoid. I have to make sure every part of the embedded image is editable. These options just make the image as a whole and not a single constituent can be selected and modified.

Comment: Ah, so you intend to import the SVG objects. That wasn't clear from your question (at least not to me). It's also going to look strange in some cases where the objects are not limited to the SVG's page area... Yes, Inkscape does not offer functionality for that by default - but you could write an extension for it.